# Как разбить форму на несколько страниц в php?

Tags: php, form

Очень много пояснений приходиться писать к форме поэтому было бы хорошо разбить ее на несколько страниц в одном документе.php
Можно на примере этой формы продемонстрировать, где и что нужно вставить, что бы браузер отображал часть формы?

```
<form action="email.php" name=mailer method=POST>

<h1>Заголовок</h1> // --- стр 1 поля формы
<p>Текст </p>
<input type=text>
<input type=text>
<input type=text>
<a>ссылка на стр 2</a>

<h1>Заголовок</h1> // --- стр 2 поля формы
<p>Текст </p>
<input type=text>
<input type=text>
<input type=text>
<a>ссылка на стр 3</a>

<h1>Заголовок</h1> // --- стр 3 отправка формы
<p>Текст </p>
<input type=text>
<input type=submit value="отправить">

</form>
```

Comment: либо js либо хранение значений в сессии а потом обработка

Comment: Сделайте js-табы

Answer (score 1):

Вот способ при котором можно разбить форму "в классическом варианте":

```
<form id="ff">
<input type="text">
<form>
. . . . . . . .
<input form="ff" type="text">
. . . . . . . .
<input form="ff" type="text">
```